# Resize lots of images (with different proportions) so each image fit in a predefined rectangle

Tags: image-processing

I have about 60 images uploaded to my site. I'd like to resize them all so they fit in a 150px × 100px box. No cropping, just scaling, but it should preserve the original proportions.

I'd prefer a simple solution using, say the ImageMagick `convert` command. A solution for a single arbitrary image is perfectly fine. (I know how to loop or use `find` in bash.)

The images are of different types (eps, jpg, ps etc) so a solution that at the same time rasterizes the image would be awesome.

Comment: Is this Imagemagick's `convert`?

Comment: Yes. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems it was easier than I expected:

```
convert image.eps -scale "150x100>" file_resized.jpg
```

did the trick. [Reference page.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry)